# Why do people refer to Bitcoin as currency when it is not classed as tender from a taxation perspective?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Bitcoin is often referred to as cryptocurrency.

In [this article from the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-56084499) the headline is "Digital currency Bitcoin has risen to a new record high of more than $50,000"

It can be used to pay out of Visa card, Mastercard, used on Paypal and even to buy Teslas.

Yet, it is subject to capital gains tax in most legislations and not deemed 'tender' according to tax/legislation.

Who is mistaken, the legislators, or the media?

EDIT/UPDATE: Most of the above was inspired by UK law [https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/info/how-to-buy-gold/paying-capital-gains-tax-on-gold/#:~:text=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20yes,British%20legal%20currency%20bullion%20coins](https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/info/how-to-buy-gold/paying-capital-gains-tax-on-gold/#:%7E:text=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20yes,British%20legal%20currency%20bullion%20coins).

Comment: Why would that be a contradiction? Currency is an asset to.

Comment: @Aganju Not sure of the right terminology. Gold is not 'currency' (i.e. tender) unless it is in coin form. Otherwise you pay capital gains tax.

Comment: @Frank Who said that gold bricks, gold ETF, and paper gold are not subject to capital gains tax?

Comment: @Frank , your question "what is currency" is a great question. But, as I explain below, your mention of "taxes" is totally irrelevant and confusing.

Comment: What does that bullion link have to do with cryptocurrency?

Comment: @RonJohn Nothing. What don't you understand?

Comment: If it has nothing to to with the question, why did you add the link to the question?

Comment: @RonJohn erm...what? i don't mean to be rude but what don't you understand. the relationship with the question is strikingly obvious

Answer (score 1):

Why would that be relevant?

What the tax man says is completely irrelevant, except for tax. If the tax man says houses are investments, does that mean we shouldn't live in them? No, it just changes how the tax is calculated.

Bitcoin was designed to be a currency, and can be used as a currency. And houses were designed to be lived in, and can be.

Comment: On the contrary, it's what the tax man says that matters.  If you don't pay tax on your Bitcoin capital gains, you risk prosecution for tax evasion.  (I wonder if the same applies to gains from currency trading, though?)  The fact that some people/companies will accept Bitcoin as payment doesn't mean it's currency (much as some people would like to think so), it's just a form of barter.  No different than if I were to offer you a bushel of peaches or a bag of diamonds to settle a debt.

Comment: @jamesqf What the tax man says matters **for tax**. Not for anything else!

Comment: @jamesqf you do have to claim capital gains for currency trading also. However the main difference is small conversions made primarily to spend (for example on holiday), are generally not presumed to he investments and are overlooked even if the change is converted back at a (slightly) different rate. The irs generally takes intent and volume into account rather than assuming any purchase is an investment or speculation.

Comment: @Vality - your example is quite wrong.  (1) say you change 20k for a holiday and end up "returning" as it were 5k and you profit $83.15.  you as surely have to put that on your tax form, as you have to put the *few cents* you make in interest from your bank savings account.  (2) the IRS couldn't care less about your internal motivation for buying/selling an item.  if you profit, you're taxed.  (3) you may be thinking of the specific differences between cap. gains and short term profits - sure, there are different rules and different taxes, but that's true of everything.

Comment: @jamesqf .. "I wonder if the same applies to gains from currency trading, though?" .. I may misunderstand you, but yes, OF COURSE when you buy and sell currencies, you pay tax on every single penny of gain. For sure!  And how!  ouch!

Comment: @Fattie this is actually a law. Not just allowed due to sloppy accounting. Up to $200 in currency conversion where the money was primarily used for travel expenses or other personal cash needs but ended up being too much is not taxable. See here https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/988 and search for the section named "Exclusion for certain personal transactions"

Comment: @jamesqf Capital gains tax is not charged on gold coins, because gold coins are legal tender.

Comment: @user253751 Gold was "designed" to be a currency, and apart from cold coins (which) are exempt from capital gains tax, gold is rarely referred to as currency. Bitcoin is increasingly used as a currency, but is primarily an asset used for speculation. Yet it is referred to as currency.

Comment: @Frank source on gold coins being legal tender?

Comment: @Frank gold was not designed

Comment: hi @Frank - I'm afraid you have been **completely misled**. Just because something is also a US coin (ie "legal tender"), it does not in any way mean that you do not pay tax on it.  You can even see this explained on a zillion "goldbug" web sites.  Random example, https://www.jmbullion.com/investing-guide/james/bullion-legal-tender-laws/ **"Now of course the IRS will want their cut of any capital gains made based on the metal content’s value appreciation and not their face value"**

Comment: @Fattie OK it seems UK law differs https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/info/how-to-buy-gold/paying-capital-gains-tax-on-gold/#:~:text=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20yes,British%20legal%20currency%20bullion%20coins.

Comment: Hi @Frank - right, in the UK there are unusual rules about certain coins.  Just FYI this is completeloy irrelevant to the USA, and to this question. Cheers

Comment: Seems that CGT tax varies a lot. None in Germany at all on gold for example.

Comment: @Fattie is it a valid rule of thumb that any conversation about gold is more likely than not to include some level of quackery?

Answer (score 1):

Cryptocurrency is *not a currency* by any traditional definition, but it **is an asset** because **people ascribe monetary worth to it**.

However, it is a *notional* currency, because it was designed to be a currency.

Assets (whether gold bars, shares of Exxon, shares of GameStop, Beanie Babies, house or Beanie Babies) which increase in value accrue *capital gains*.

Those capital gains are taxed unless (like primary housing) explicitly excluded.

Thus, *you* are wrong, and the media -- as usual -- is sloppy.  (We all call it cryptocurrency, so we're all sloppy is usage.)

Comment: Of course this answer is totally correct.  I can see there's a "disinformationist" unfortunately downvoting correct answers here.  In the "gold N guns" US subculture there is a (patently absurd) myth that "Silver Eagles" are not taxed and this sometimes gets conflated to other issues about gold/etc being "not taxed".  It's a bit like in the US, in some regional areas, you get people who assert they do not need a license plate on their car due to a certain biblical passage mentioned in the constitution or such, and instead of a license plate they have a message to that effect. Good grief.

Comment: So it seems my EU/UK base has rules that dont apply in the US https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/info/how-to-buy-gold/paying-capital-gains-tax-on-gold/#:~:text=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20yes,British%20legal%20currency%20bullion%20coins.

Comment: @Frank Brexit, so... UK base.  And my answer does say, "unless explicitly excluded". (I've got to edit that for grammar.)  just as importantly, the examples in your link are in the too-good-to-be-true arena.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion here.  "Currency" is simply ...

- Currency is just money that is **commonly and generally used** (in a given time and place)

That's all it means.

For example, Euros are *not* currency in New York.  But of course Euros are currency in Lyon.

In Calais (it's a town in France very close to England), Euros are of course currency, and it's fair to say that English money is also currency, or pretty close - many shops, people, taxis etc will take English money in Calais.

We've all heard that certain island nations used Shells as currency in the old days.

And so on.

Note that indeed you can argue about whether something "is a currency".

Indeed, is bitcoin or ethereum a "currency"? - well, I'd say no, you can not use them at my local supermarket in the US. On the other hand, they are surely gaining usage - maybe in a few years (or less!) we will all say, "Obviously ethereum is a currency, I just used it at Dunkin' Donuts!"

Or for example, someone might say "Fattie is an idiot, only a few shops in Calais take English pounds, of course pounds are not currency in Calais."

That's all "currency" means.

--

Note that you mention "taxes".

This has no connection at all to anything mentioned here, and, no relationship to whether it's a "currency" or not.

If you're a market trader and you trade *any* currency, *any* commodity, *any* stock or anything like say houses ... of course you pay tax.  Lots of day traders in the USA trade the USD.  Obviously they pay tax.

(Could it be you think that *"if something is a currency, it has no capital gains tax"* .. or something.  That is (A) totally wrong and (B) there's just no connection there, it doesn't even make sense.)

--

Just to completely repeat:

1. You may think there is an "official definition" of currency.  No, it just means that "it is used commonly as money".  That's all it means.  **There is utterly no "official" definition of currency or similar terms.**
2. You may think that there is some connection between tax and "currency". There's no connection whatsoever.
3. If you hold some (say) Canadian dollars and later sell them and you have made a profit, you (of course) get taxed on that.  There is no difference whatsoever with literally anything.  If you hold an oil painting, gold, bitcoin, stocks, shares, antiques, houses .. whatever .. if it goes up when you sell it you pay tax.  This has no connection, at all in any way, to issues like money, currency, etc.

Comment: That's not correct. There is a legal definition of 'tender' (currency) and gold coins are exempt from capital gains tax because they are legal tender. Gold blocks are not legal tender and therefore subject to capital gains tax.

Comment: Hi @Frank - that's completely, totally, absolutely, fully wrong in every way.  I suggest you delete the comment as it spreads disinformation?  (Could it be you've seen the "urban myth" that "Silver Eagles are exempt from tax!"  That is purely an **urban myth**.  Sadly!) You can trivially google 10000 pages explaining tax on gold .. https://goldsilver.com/blog/irs-1099-gold-reporting-private-gold-private-silver-bullion/

Comment: This is the case in the UK for certain gold coins by looks of it: https://www.royalmint.com/gold-price/capital-gains-tax-on-investments/#:~:text=Our%20UK%20bullion%20coins%2C%20including,only%20the%20gain%20is%20taxable.